# Avoiding double lookup in Map

Tags: java

I have a performance-critical tight loop which, for a large number of keys, needs to look up the key in a map and do something with that key if it exists in the map:

```
Map<Integer, SomeClass> map = ...;
for (int i : someLargeIterable)
    if (map.containsKey(i))
        doSomething(i, map.get(i));
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid looking up the key in the map twice (once with `containsKey` and then again with `get`). Is it possible?

If I could guarantee that the map does not contain null values, I could do this:

```
    var value = map.get(i);
    if (value != null)
        doSomething(i, value);
```

Unfortunately, I can't do that because sometimes the map can contain null values, which I want to pass to `doSomething`.

One way I had thought of was to use `computeIfPresent`:

```
    map.computeIfPresent(i, (key, value) -> {
        doSomething(key, value);
        return value;
    });
```

But that re-inserts `value` back into the map, so again we're doing a double lookup. Is there, maybe, something similar to `computeIfPresent` that doesn't try to modify the map? Maybe something that involves `Optional`?

Comment: "But that re-inserts value back into the map" Have you actually confirmed whether this is a performance issue? Implementations of Map could be optimized so it doesn't actually have to find the place in the map again.

Comment: Assuming null values are rare, and that most keys you query with are in the map, you could call `get` first and then only call `containsKey` if the value was null.

Comment: In support of Andy's point, the [`HashMap` implementation of `computeIfPresent`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2af0312c958e693b1377f4c014ae8f84cabf6b83/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L1262) simply assigns the returned value to the node it had previously looked up (i.e., no performance cost).

Comment: However, given you can have `null` values, `computeIfPresent` will not work for you: "_If the value for the specified key is present **and non-null**, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value_" -- [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

Comment: @Slaw true. It seems like avoiding having `null` values in the map would be a generally good idea; you could instead store a [Null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#Java).

Comment: Good point @Slaw. Also, if the map happened to be an immutable/unmodifiable type, `computeIfPresent` wouldn't work in such situation too. And if it happened to be a `LinkedHashMap` it would alter its iteration order when I don't want to modify it. So `computeIfPresent` is not an option.

Comment: Thanks, I think a Null Object would be a great idea in this situation.

Comment: Changing the value associated with a key in a LinkedHashMap doesn't change the iteration order.

Comment: @AndyTurner it depends on the value of `accessOrder`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,float,boolean)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the comments to my question, which I'll summarise as options for future readers, and give an additional possible solution of my own (option 3):

**Option 1**
If null values are rare, you can avoid double lookup most of the time by doing it only if the value is null:

```
var value = map.get(i);
if (value != null || map.containsKey(i))
    doSomething(i, value);
```

**Option 2**
Null values in maps are generally a bad idea. You can use a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#Java) instead of null values:

```
var value = map.get(i);
if (value != null)
    doSomething(i, value == NullObject ? null : value);
```

**Option 3**
You can use `getOrDefault` with a default that is guaranteed not to exist in the map. This way, null values are still coming through.

```
private static final SomeClass sentinel = new SomeClass(...);
...
var value = map.getOrDefault(i, sentinel);
if (value != sentinel)  // identity comparison is deliberate; don't use equals()
    doSomething(i, value);
```

Comment: Your sentinel could simply be `new Object()` – plain Object instances are guaranteed to have identity equality.

Comment: @knittl but the type of the value has to be `V`, the parameterized type the map was declared with, doesn't it?

Comment: Fair point. I usually wrap my Maps if they need to support such behavior. Then I can hide this implementation detail from consumers of the map.